# How to create an attribute conditionally in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, attributes, wai-aria

I am trying to create `aria-current` attribute in an anchor only if the anchors `href` is equal to the current windows path. Basically, I want `aria-current="page"` IF the anchor in question has an `href` equal to the window in views path. And I do not want to create an `aria-current` attribute if the anchor in question does not have an `href` equal to the window in view path.

Is there a way to write an conditional statement inline that will create or not create an attribute in AngularJS (Angular1)?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no "inline way" to do this, but for this case you can create a directive

Here an Example:

```
yourmodule.directive('myexampleblabla', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) { 
        if(elem.attr('href') === windows.location.href){
            elem.attr('aria-current', true)
        }
    },
    restrict: 'E',
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="sample/path#a123" myexampleblabla>Your Anchor</a>
```

Be aware: This code in untested, but it should bring you a few steps forward.

For every case where you want to modify the DOM within a angular application you should create a directive. Read more about directives here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2):

Solution: use `ng-attr` to conditionally create an attribute inline.

For example `<div ng-attr-alt="{{<conditional statement> ? '<value to set attr to if true>' : undefined }}"`

If the conditional statement does not evaluate to true then the attribute will not be created, the undefined value sets this.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for Angularjs

Bind your title with below code

title="{{ condition == true ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'}}"

```js
title="{{item.IsStatus ? 'Inactive' : 'Active'}}"
```